# No data in my popover

Tags: ios, popover

I am trying to display a list in my popover but all I get is a blank popover with the following message in the console:-

> `-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]`: the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. This will be an exception in a future release.

Comment: it appears you're passing in a CGRect with a width or height of zero.

Comment: show your code of creating `UIPopoverController`

Answer (score 1):

Actually this could happen when the you either dont have a frame because you didn't connect the iboutlet of the button or the frame you sets as in the following is nil

```
[popoverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES]
```

If the button frame is nil, then or you give empty frame you'll get error

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are giving it an invalid or zero rectangle.